# Specify unpacked extension directory and mobile emulation together in chromeOptions for Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I can specify those two separately and they are working fine:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions (note: I want unpacked directory and not packed crx)

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

So when combining both, I need to create a `new ChromeOptions()` object for the former and `new HashMap()` object for the latter both as Chrome Options, when setting the capabilities, I can only set one as if I set both the latter will overwrite the former

Answer (score 0):

I was somewhat successful in doing this using the "extensions" argument that receives a list of base64 encoded extension files.

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Apple iPhone 6");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

try {
    chromeOptions.put("extensions", singletonList(Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(WebDriverManager
        .class.getResource("/extension_2_1_0.crx").toURI())))));
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed
driver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");
// setup ModHeader with headers
driver.executeScript(
"localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
        "  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
        "  headers: [                                                      " +
        "    {enabled: true, name: 'headerName', value: 'headerValue', comment: ''}, " +
         "  ],                                                              " +
         "  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
        "  filters: []                                                     " +
        "}]));                                                             ");
return driver;
```